# Library that evaluates writing quality recommendation?

Tags: api, artificial-intelligence, writing

I am looking to implement an AI in my project that will evaluate writing quality (much like paperrater.com/ does).

Does anyone have any specific recommendations? I know there are many APIs for grammar and spelling checking, but I want a more sophisticated library with vocabulary level measurement and a general objective "grade."

TLDR: I'm looking for a Python API or library that performs sophisticated writing quality evaluation (beyond the simple grammar spelling checking).